# I have two networks in the office with their own IP ranges. I need to see them both from my computer

Tags: network-shares

Network One is 192.168.2.xxx 
Network Two is  192.168.1.xxx

Computer One is 192.168.2.xxx and assigned IP automatically.
IP 192.168.2.157
GW 192.168.2.1
DHCP 192.168.2.1
DNS 192.168.2.1
Windows 7 Home Premium

Computer Two is 192.168.1.220 and static IP
Windows XP Professional

How can I see Computer Two from Computer One?

P.S. I cannot change IP addresses as Network Two is running on a network of 5 point of sale computers.

Computer One is essentially a backoffice PC and needs to see Computer One which is the POS Server.

So again, how do I do it?

Comment: Are the computers on the same physical network?

Comment: It seems like it would be easier to put one of the computers on both networks.

Comment: @Bacon Yes, they are. Infact on the same switch as well.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Yes, but how? I heard that we can have two IP addresses on one NIC? Also, I cannot put another NIC on Computer One.

Comment: What *precisely* do you mean by "see them both"? Is there a router connecting the two networks?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, the common switch goes into the modem/router

Comment: You can certainly have a single computer on both wired and wireless at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways to do this, but the easiest is to assign two network addresses to the interface on Computer One.  Since you're on the same physical network, you can do this pretty easily.  This is called *multi-homing*.  The only drawback to this is that you can't use DHCP.  You'll have to manually assign both addresses on the computer.

Before you begin, you should know the IP address and subnet mask that Computer One will have on the normal network (192.168.2.xxx), the DNS server(s) that that network uses, and the default gateway for that network.  You should also know what IP address you want Computer One to use on the POS network (192.168.1.xxx), and the DNS server that network uses (if any).  You do not necessarily need a default gateway for this network.

Computer One is a Windows 7 system, so go **Start** → **Control Panel** → **View network status and tasks** → **Change adapter settings** (listed on the left).  Right-click on the active network adapter on Computer One, and choose **Properties**.  The properties dialog box should appear.

Select **Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)** and click **Properties**.  Another properties dialog box should appear.  On the General tab, change the setting to **Use the following IP address** then click the **Advanced** button.  The Advanced TCP/IP settings window will open.

On the **IP Settings** tab, under IP addresses, click **Add**, and add the IP address and subnet for the normal (192.168.2.xxx) network.  Repeat, and add the IP address and subnet for the POS network.  Under **Default gateways** click **Add** and add the default gateway for the 192.168.2.xxx network.  You can also add the default gateway for the POS network, but this should not be necessary.  I wouldn't add the POS gateway unless you know you need it for some reason.

Now click on the **DNS** tab.  Click the **Add** button, and add the DNS server(s) for the normal network and the POS network.

Click **OK** to close all the open dialog boxes, and you should now be able to ping the POS computer's IP.  You *should* be able to use the POS computer's hostname, but you will probably have more success with the IP address.

Comment: Thanks Bacon. I was doing part of what you suggested and failing to see the Computer Two. I was missing the DNS when adding the second IP. Also, I kept trying to access it using the hostname and simply forgot that I could also use the IP. Noob, I am. It seems to work for now. I'll test it thoroughly on my development environment before applying the settings on production. I'll get back to you later.

Comment: Cool beans.  It's always easy to skip things that are simple.  If you continue to have problems the next thing I'd do is add a second physical network interface to Computer One and put that on the POS network.  You may have a situation where you can't have the POS network on the same physical network as the rest of the system, for example.  That configuration would solve that situation without setting up a router between the two networks (which also may not be what you'd want).

Comment: Yea, the thing is I cannot add another NIC on Computer One right now. I would do it as an last resort though whenever I am able to. Hence my research on a solution using existing systems in place.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear as to whether or not you have two routers in your environment. If so, you'll need to configure routes in between both networks.

It sounds like you have this computer on the same network switch as the others but it is simply obtaining a DHCP address out of the range of the other statically assigned workstations. (POS's)

Just configure a static address on computer one matching the network settings of the other network (using a unique address of course.)

Comment: The switch is connected to a modem router that assigns the IP addresses on network one and this network has internet access. Network Two is not allowed internet access for obvious reasons being a POS environment. Computer One needs to communicate with Computer to access shared folders and for other reasons. I am happy to set a fixed IP on Computer One if the solutions calls for it.